# How to achieve scroll functionality based on properties in React?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am building a sports website using React, I am receiving the data from a sports API - API-Football. I have a fixtures page that displays fixtures for a specific league based on league id. So, what I would want is to display the data in this manner - [English Premier League](https://www.google.com/search?q=english%20premier%20league&rlz=1C1JJTC_enIN959IN959&oq=english%20premier%20league&aqs=chrome..69i57.3278j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#cobssid=s&sie=lg;/g/11pz7zbpnb;2;/m/02_tc;mt;fp;1;;;).

See how the fixtures that have finished can be accessed only when the user scrolls up whereas the fixtures that have not yet been started are visible to the user screen and more such fixtures that have not yet been started can be accessed when the user scrolls down.

I am receiving an array of objects from the API. And this is the sample of an object I am receiving from the API -

```
{
    "fixture": {
        "id": 867946,
        "referee": "Anthony Taylor, England",
        "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "date": "2022-08-06T00:30:00+05:30",
        "timestamp": 1659726000,
        "periods": {
            "first": 1659726000,
            "second": 1659729600
        },
        "venue": {
            "id": 525,
            "name": "Selhurst Park",
            "city": "London"
        },
        "status": {
            "long": "Match Finished",
            "short": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90
        }
    },
    "league": {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "Premier League",
        "country": "England",
        "logo": "https://media-1.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png",
        "flag": "https://media-3.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg",
        "season": 2022,
        "round": "Regular Season - 1"
    },
    "teams": {
        "home": {
            "id": 52,
            "name": "Crystal Palace",
            "logo": "https://media-3.api-sports.io/football/teams/52.png",
            "winner": false
        },
        "away": {
            "id": 42,
            "name": "Arsenal",
            "logo": "https://media-1.api-sports.io/football/teams/42.png",
            "winner": true
        }
    },
    "goals": {
        "home": 0,
        "away": 2
    },
    "score": {
        "halftime": {
            "home": 0,
            "away": 1
        },
        "fulltime": {
            "home": 0,
            "away": 2
        },
        "extratime": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        },
        "penalty": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here I would recommend using refs (with functional components, using the `useRef` hook, [hook references](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)). For each fixture, you can assign a given ref to the component (assuming each fixture is mapped to its own component). If the fixtures are sorted by completion, record the first incomplete fixture, or conversely the last completed fixture. If you're going with the first incomplete fixture, you can adjust the parent component's `scrollTop` to match the `top` of the client bounding rect for the incomplete fixture -- this can be grabbed using `{ref}.current.getClientBoundingRect()`, [getClientBoundingRect reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). In a similar fashion, if you decide to use the last completed fixture, you can assign the `bottom` attribute of the client bounding rect to the parent's `scrollTop`.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I basically need to make use of the `getClientBoundingRect()`.
Thanks.